# rgbdslam_v2 evaluation problem

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using rgbdslam_v2 with the datasets from http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset.  After executing ./run_tests.sh, the processing is done. But there are some problems with evaluation. The print is here:

18:30:27 Finished processing rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hjzhang/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo//rgbd_benchmark/evaluate_ate.py", line 2, in 
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
ImportError: No module named pyximport
Evaluation Failed

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 0 are stored in /home/hjzhang/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/1/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_0.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hjzhang/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo//rgbd_benchmark/evaluate_ate.py", line 2, in 
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
ImportError: No module named pyximport
Evaluation Failed

I really have to resolve this problem. Does any one have the same problem or some ideas to solve this problem? Thanks very much!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223754/rgbdslam_v2-evaluation-problem/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to install cython (`apt-get install cython`). It's not in the dependencies list, because the evaluation scripts are optional, but I should have mentioned it in the README.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on 2016-01-17**:
@Felix Thanks. Solved.